# pip3 install does not seem to support --install-option anymore

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

With:

- pip 20.3.4-4 or 21.3.1
- python3.9 3.9.8-1 or 3.9.9-1
- python3-setuptools 59.6.0 or 60.0.3

and build-requirements.txt containing:

```
. --install-option='--install-purelib=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
```

the following command fails to install the package from source (pygments in this instance):

```
python3 -m pip install . --root="../package-build" --prefix=/usr -r build-requirements.txt
ERROR: Location-changing options found in --install-option: ['--install-purelib'] from file:///git-pygments (from -r build-requirements.txt (line 1)). This is unsupported, use pip-level options like --user, --prefix, --root, and --target instead.
```

Using --install-option on the CLI level (instead of inside a requirements file) has a similar fate.

However, the official docs state that the usage of --install-option is supported:

- [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides)
- ['Installing Python Modules (Legacy version)' documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#custom-installation)

Am I missing something or is this an issue with pip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `--install-option` was [deprecated](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#deprecations-and-removals) in `pip` v22.3 and [has been removed completely](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1) in v23.1.  I can't say why it wasn't working when you posted, but it's definitely gone now.

I know those links say '`--install-options` [sic]', but I don't think it matters.  See discussion at
https://discuss.python.org/t/passing-command-line-arguments-to-pip-install-after-install-options-deprecation/22981.

Answer (score 2):

Use `--config-settings` instead.